# TCP Socket Peer2peer

Tags: c, tcp, p2p

I'm working on TCP peer-2-peer connection but I'm getting error below in the picrure . it could be varable type error
[image]

ARGUMENTS

```
char name[20];
int PORT;
char ip[15];
char ip[15];
void sending();
void receiving(int server_fd);
void *receive_thread(void *server_fd);
```

I'm getting error because of this

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip; //. <== here
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_server);
```

is this how to deal with IP address or Im missing something
error

try to have peers to connect to another peers

Comment: You need to call a function like `inet_aton()` to convert an IP in a string to its numeric form.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, output or error messages. Copy the content as text.

Comment: Don't use code from ancient history. Use `getaddrinfo` to set up your socket parameters.

Comment: I kinda new to StackOverflow, not sure posting picture against the policy

Answer (score 1):

Use `inet_aton()` to parse an IP string.

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton(ip);
```